# Javascript object's prototype property

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I have a question about prototype object.

I learned that constructor function has prototype property (not [[prototype]] property) and it indicates prototype object.

ex) If function's name is Person, prototype object's name will be Person.prototype

So I typed this code below.

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var foo = new Person('foo');

console.dir(Person);
```

If my thought is right, Person function's prototype property has to point Person.prototype but actual result is different.

[image: screenshot of my browser]

But my book says:

[image: photograph of my book]

Why is Person.prototype's name 'Object' ??? I don't know why... 
My mental is going to be broken...

Someone please answer.. :(

Comment: `Person` is a type of Object, isn't it? A lot of things in JavaScript are.

Comment: Yes, I know that. but My book's example show me the result like `prototype: Person`. why are these results different?

Comment: How old is that book? What browser are you using?

Comment: What the console shows you is not standardized. Objects don't have "names". Some browsers might show the "name" of `Person.prototype` as `Person` because `Person.prototype.constructor.name` is `'Person'`. For the same reason `foo`'s "name" might appear as `Person` because `foo.constructor.name` is `'Person'` (you may have guessed thast `Person.prototype.constructor === foo.constructor === Person`). The console is trying to be helpful but sometimes it's rather confusing. Fo

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Objects don't have names; variables do. Variables can contain objects.

Comment: @tadman may 2015, chrome!

Comment: The prototype's *constructor* is the `Person` object, not the prototype itself.

Comment: guys I additionally upload image that book's result . Please show this. Why are these results different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Person()` function has a `prototype` property. `Person().prototype` is called `Object` because it is indeed an object. In console, it is purely saying that the prototype property is an object.

Because of the constructor name, it displays Person, possibly because the author used a different JavaScript/Browser version, or another version entirely. The 'Object' that you get is normal, and your code should work normally. You can ignore the difference.

A function's `prototype` property is to  allow you to add properties to your code. Here is an example:

```
function Person(name, age, id) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.id = id;
}

var me = new Person("Brian", 12, 0);
```

Then later on in the code if you want to add a property to the person function, like my favorite programming languages:

```
Person.prototype.favLanguages = null;
```

When you want to define my favorite languages you can do:

```
me.favLanguages = ['JavaScript', 'Java', 'HTML', 'CSS'];
```

Comment: It's standard practice to capitalize the initial letter of constructor functions. (c.f. `Date`, `String` etc.)

Comment: Oh.... right. On the mention of 'constructor' I remembered, haha. I was thinking more of standard functions. Thanks a lot!